# how to open aliexpress app in browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="linkHere" id="idHere">Click me</a>
```

in the linkHere section, its link that comes from the back-end  (in the link the redirector on aliexpress web site).
If you click on this link from mobile browser, a window will open (native), which will prompt you to open the link (in the browser or if the person has an aliexpress application, then he will offer the same).

What is the complexity. There is a timer in a few seconds, if a person has not clicked on the link I wrote above, then you also need to show the native window (by which to open the link: browser or application ali). The hours of google did not help ... Can someone come across this? Thank you!

Comment: What should happen when you click this link? Should it open the AliExpress app or should it scroll to another part of your website?

Comment: @Luca, thx for help. Should open native modal in mobile browser. In which i can select app with the help of i will open the link (example: via browser, via google chrome, via aliepress app)

Comment: You should change the linkHere to a link that AliExpress uses to deep link content in their app

Comment: @Luca, if i click on link then all is ok. Modal is show. But if i do something like this:
document.querySelector('.classHere').click()

its didnt work. Modal is hidden and occurs only redirect...